# How to arrange multiple boxplots in one "meta" graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Disclaimer: I'm a total newbie regarding R, especially data visualization; so I apologize if this is trivial. I just have no idea how to approach this.

I have four variables, say, X, Y, Z, W, each with a "high" and "low" value (e.g. big X and little x).
Hence, there are 16 combinations, e.g. XYzw, XyZw, xyZw, etc.
For each combination, I obtained a boxplot.
(Each combination is an experiment that was executed multiples times, each spitting a numeric value.)
I want to arrange these boxplots in one "meta" plot by arranging the combinations of two variables on the x-axis and the other two on the y-axis.
For example, the x-axis could consist of the values XY, Xy, xY, xy, and the y-axis of the values ZW, Zw, zW, zw.
Then, each point in the graph is a boxplot corresponding to a combination.

**Edit 1:**

My data has the following shape:

```
combs <- data.frame(xyzw=sample(1:100,10),xyzW=sample(1:100,10),xyZW=sample(1:100,10),xyZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    xYzW=sample(1:100,10),xYzw=sample(1:100,10),xYZW=sample(1:100,10),xYZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    XyzW=sample(1:100,10),Xyzw=sample(1:100,10),XyZW=sample(1:100,10),XyZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    XYzW=sample(1:100,10),XYzw=sample(1:100,10),XYZW=sample(1:100,10),XYZw=sample(1:100,10))
```

I could plot 16 boxplots by looping through each column, e.g. `for (comb in combs) { boxplot(comb) }`, but how can I plot a graph where the x-axis has values XY, Xy, xY, xy, the y-axis has values ZW, Zw, zW, zw, and each data point is a boxplot?

Comment: Perhaps the [`facet_grid()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) function could be used for this purpose? The examples in the documentation look similar to what you're describing (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html#ref-examples) but without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'm afraid I can't say whether it will solve your problem or not. If you could please edit your question to include a small subset of your data (or an example dataset) it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, it is very close to what I want, but I couldn't figure out how to apply the `facet_grid()` to my data yet. I added an example to my question that is identical to the data I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for updating your question! There are a few ways to handle this task. One potential option is to 'pivot' your data to 'long format' (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html), then separate the name column (i.e. xyzW) into two 'new' columns (i.e. "xy", "zw") using `separate()` from the tidyr package, then use these 'new' columns to make the grid:

```r
library(tidyverse)
combs <- data.frame(xyzw=sample(1:100,10),xyzW=sample(1:100,10),xyZW=sample(1:100,10),xyZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    xYzW=sample(1:100,10),xYzw=sample(1:100,10),xYZW=sample(1:100,10),xYZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    XyzW=sample(1:100,10),Xyzw=sample(1:100,10),XyZW=sample(1:100,10),XyZw=sample(1:100,10),
                    XYzW=sample(1:100,10),XYzw=sample(1:100,10),XYZW=sample(1:100,10),XYZw=sample(1:100,10))

combs %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("xy", "zw"), sep = c(2,4)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(xy), cols = vars(zw), scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this approach work with your actual data?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! I loved how the code is concise, didn't expect that. I need to learn this tidyverse! Haha

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)